# Is it possible to give an App Registration a Role in a Client Credential Flow?

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have a .Net Core Web API "A" that is being called by both Client "B" and Client "C".

I want to restrict access some parts of the API by granting Client C a Role?

I have read this guide
https://joonasw.net/view/defining-permissions-and-roles-in-aad

But it requires for an app to consent. I want to  bypass that consent since these are all background apps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the approach you're trying to follow based on the blog (which is pretty detailed) is correct and it works fine. I'll show a sample token acquired based on this approach at the end.

> I want to bypass that consent since these are all background apps.

You will NOT be able to bypass the admin consent process for Application permissions.

You can read more about it here on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-permissions-and-consent#types-of-permissions). Here is a small excerpt

[image]

Good part though is that it's a one time process (unless an admin revokes it intentionally at some later point), i.e. once the Administrator provides consent for application, you will not need to repeat the process as part of acquiring token or making calls to your API.

**Options**:

1. Use the Admin consent endpoint. This is the most common and convenient way. You can read more about it here.. [Request Permissions from Directory Admin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#request-the-permissions-from-a-directory-admin)

   ```
    GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/adminconsent?client_id={yourclientid}&state=12345&redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/permissions
   ```
2. Create `appRoleAssignment` for Service Principal using Azure AD Graph API.

**Sample Decoded Token with roles**

Here is a sample token acquired through client credential grant after defining and assigning custom application permissions like your case.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rohit! I initially didn't want to have Admin grant permission, but it seems like this is the only way to get this scenario to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Authorized client applications" section in the "Expose an Api" blade of your app registration in the new Azure AD portal to pre-consent apps.

A code walk through for the scenario you are trying to is provided [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V8VUPixLSiM&t=1595s).